# Mern app working locally - 503 error on Heroku (H10-H13)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

I have made a project through a course with Brad Traversy called contact keeper. It works fine locally on my machine and I get contact with the database.

Once I push it to Heroku I cant log in or register anymore. I get a 503 error (H10 & H13 errors from heroku) saying service unavailable when trying to hit those endpoints.

I have tried looking on similar threads but it does not work for me. I have added a procfile and checked through my package.json and it looks alright (from what I see).

The full repository can be found here: https://github.com/Dannus90/Contact_Keeper_MERN

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'));

// Serve static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

In the picture below you can see where it fails. It is in the AuthState file when it tries to hit the endpoints.

[image: Where it fails img]

The complete error log from heroku can be seen below:

```
2020-05-17T09:23:20.616623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T09:23:50.230066+00:00 app[web.1]: connection <monitor> to 52.31.65.44:27017 closed
2020-05-17T09:23:50.240114+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-17T09:23:50.240313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-17T09:23:50.241253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! contact-keeper@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-05-17T09:23:50.241374+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-17T09:23:50.241498+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-17T09:23:50.241622+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the contact-keeper@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-17T09:23:50.241760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
2020-05-17T09:23:50.249534+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-17T09:23:50.249723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-17T09:23:50.249843+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-17T09_23_50_242Z-debug.log
2020-05-17T09:23:50.311445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T09:26:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:28:20.734327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-17T09:28:20.461350+00:00 app[api]: Release v48 created by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:28:20.461350+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 502ce232 by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:28:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-17T09:28:30.543747+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:28:30.543761+00:00 app[web.1]: > contact-keeper@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-17T09:28:30.543761+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-05-17T09:28:30.543762+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:28:31.157953+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 13966
2020-05-17T09:28:32.044290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T09:28:33.217189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=ed1492f5-d053-4ecf-8a88-8561992f3403 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2626 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:33.348570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.abec718a.chunk.css" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=410da44d-797f-4a41-bafe-f130118e8c6d fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=4578 protocol=https 
2020-05-17T09:28:33.346039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.6e77bd50.chunk.js" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=018e556e-91d6-4944-bd6e-0c5b74ece68a fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=28978 protocol=https  
2020-05-17T09:28:33.474881+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.9c49eab7.chunk.js" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=5379490e-fd9b-47c1-b001-15e036784e2d fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=192222 protocol=https   
2020-05-17T09:28:33.992494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/contacts" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=3684bbba-83b1-4d90-b9f8-d4ba7dedbc60 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=401 bytes=257 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:33.990977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=705c0086-3927-4e6f-b2dd-45ac9165e303 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=401 bytes=257 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:34.365542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=1f38b786-2c3d-411e-8aee-6862c40e77d4 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=787 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:34.483877+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=65807958-8954-4332-8cab-dc4320e2cac8 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5622 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:42.084546+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.9c49eab7.chunk.js.map" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=d186f408-b227-4ce3-8f6d-2858c2b6b5a0 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=624338 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:42.056584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.abec718a.chunk.css" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=4ebde32e-fca4-4968-89d2-e10af56e5ad3 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=238 protocol=https  
2020-05-17T09:28:42.176331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.6e77bd50.chunk.js.map" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=22d537d1-9c6e-445b-985a-78f2319dd192 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=61221 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:28:42.289347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.abec718a.chunk.css.map" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=7418f08d-9c43-47e0-b2d3-2f2d23652356 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=15892 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:01.254923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=82f5a82c-e065-4e9e-a284-a82ba86287d2 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15877ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:01.362981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T09:29:01.235846+00:00 app[web.1]: connection <monitor> to 54.72.107.147:27017 closed
2020-05-17T09:29:01.262738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-17T09:29:01.263049+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-17T09:29:01.263998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! contact-keeper@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-05-17T09:29:01.264159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-17T09:29:01.264337+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-17T09:29:01.264484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the contact-keeper@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-17T09:29:01.264618+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
2020-05-17T09:29:01.270789+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:29:01.270997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-17T09:29:01.271145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-17T09_29_01_265Z-debug.log
2020-05-17T09:29:01.256625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=0e0e84a4-257b-43bd-a31d-b97ebaed5a10 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16031ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:01.256627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=acbb4fdf-bf07-4668-886e-a253a3e0aee3 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15442ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:01.257557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=1a45a04e-0c1e-47ea-b796-7299db72f732 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21480ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:01.257996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/api/auth" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=2531aa80-5bf8-42e8-b620-ff9f2969ba1f fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15579ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:29:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:30:32.857023+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-17T09:30:32.560586+00:00 app[api]: Release v49 created by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:30:32.560586+00:00 app[api]: Deploy aba0d37e by user persson.daniel.1990@gmail.com
2020-05-17T09:30:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-17T09:30:44.786119+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:30:44.786136+00:00 app[web.1]: > contact-keeper@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-17T09:30:44.786137+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-05-17T09:30:44.786137+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:30:45.574040+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 52681
2020-05-17T09:30:46.081535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T09:31:15.677435+00:00 app[web.1]: connection <monitor> to 52.31.65.44:27017 closed
2020-05-17T09:31:15.698356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-17T09:31:15.698666+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-17T09:31:15.699733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! contact-keeper@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-05-17T09:31:15.699922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-17T09:31:15.700135+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-17T09:31:15.700312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the contact-keeper@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-17T09:31:15.700467+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
2020-05-17T09:31:15.723946+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:31:15.724237+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-17T09:31:15.724392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-17T09_31_15_704Z-debug.log
2020-05-17T09:31:15.828237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T09:35:10.524783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-17T09:35:21.345206+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:35:21.345238+00:00 app[web.1]: > contact-keeper@1.0.0 start /app
2020-05-17T09:35:21.345238+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-05-17T09:35:21.345239+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:35:22.181653+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 57715
2020-05-17T09:35:22.526258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-17T09:35:52.241989+00:00 app[web.1]: connection <monitor> to 54.72.107.147:27017 closed
2020-05-17T09:35:52.255501+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-17T09:35:52.256048+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-17T09:35:52.257707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! contact-keeper@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2020-05-17T09:35:52.258009+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-17T09:35:52.258313+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-17T09:35:52.258505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the contact-keeper@1.0.0 start script.
2020-05-17T09:35:52.258686+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
2020-05-17T09:35:52.266384+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-17T09:35:52.266689+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-17T09:35:52.266864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-17T09_35_52_259Z-debug.log
2020-05-17T09:35:52.425747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-17T09:37:40.075229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=b86ff65a-3c2f-4609-85ba-a75500f93e3a fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:37:40.189972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=d5b50b56-a5df-4d19-9c0f-6298c0dea421 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:37:42.254860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=20cdf3b9-5883-4dcd-898a-03eb6ee20dc5 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:37:43.970046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=dc0e7da8-46fa-4da1-bdb6-4814157e43a5 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-17T09:37:44.242232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=afternoon-earth-34040.herokuapp.com request_id=53adb339-25bb-4bca-9b89-638035820973 fwd="78.82.2.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the code from my db file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

This is the database (found in default and production.js):

```
{
    "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://Daniel123:Daniel123@contactkeeper-rjjr4.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "jwtSecret": "secret"
}
```

Comment: It mentions a connection to :27017 in the logs, which is Mongo's conventional port. Where is the DB your app is attempting to connect to?

Comment: const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;

Comment: Above is from the db.js file. Then in production.json I got this:"mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://Daniel123:Daniel123@contactkeeper-rjjr4.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

Comment: I updated up above also so its easier to see. It on the bottom of the message.

Comment: Well we can't see what actually handles the request in question. Have you tried debugging the server, rather than the client? Please give a [mre]. Also note you now need to rotate your database credentials.

Comment: Yeah I found where it goes wrong as shown in the picture above. In the AuthState file it goes wrong when it tries to reach this (only when its on Heroku thoguh): const res = await axios.post("/api/auth", formData, config); It works until just before that. Same is when you register. It works until it tries to hit /api/auth. I try make a small example (not yet so experienced). Thanks for the password reminder!

Comment: That picture (don't post pictures of code) just shows us *which request fails*. The error is 503, which means the problem's on the server side, not the client side. Therefore the error is somewhere in routes/auth (not shown).

Comment: Ok will avoid pictures of code. I am wondering if the problem is that I ignore the following in .gitignore: node_modules/
/config/production.json
/config/default.json
When I then push to heroku the database link is not included (from the config files since they are ignored) and when I then try to import it in my db file there is no database to get when its uploaded to Heroku. Could that be the problem? Thanks for all your help btw! I am checking server side I agree the problem is somewhere there for sure. I think its failing to reach the db when it gets on heroku.

Comment: That could be the problem, that configuration won't be on Heroku at all; I would recommend getting environment-specific configuration via env vars (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Damn I dont get it to work:/ I set enviromental variables in heroku for both jwtSecret and mongoURI and then did like this in the code: await mongoose.connect(db || process.env.mongoURI -- Still getting the same problem.

Comment: I got it working now! I had to whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 on mongodb .... Thanks for all help jonrsharpe, it was appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me for this problem (incase anyone else get the problem):

I whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 on mongodb, set environmental variables on heroku and set them as an alternative for the db connect(same with jwtSecret in the config), since the config was ignored when pushing to heroku:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db || process.env.mongoURI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Comment: Note that whitelisting the whole internet isn't the most secure option, see e.g. https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku for others.